# Join clause to return results from both tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Please see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6552d/4

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Figure(
MonthNumber varchar(10),
Code varchar(10),
Figure int
);

INSERT INTO Figure (MonthNumber, Code, Figure)
VALUES ('5', 'S', '25'),
('5','G', '30'),
('4','K', '30');

CREATE TABLE Person(
Code varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Person (Code)
VALUES ('S'),
('G' ),
('K' ),
('D' ),
('J');
```

Query:

```
SELECT F.[MonthNumber],
f.[Code],
f.[Figure]
FROM 
Figure F
RIGHT JOIN Person P
ON F.[Code] = P.[Code]

WHERE F.[MonthNumber] = '5'
```

Result:

```
| MonthNumber | Code | Figure |
|-------------|------|--------|
|           5 |    S |     25 |
|           5 |    G |     30 |
```

But i am looking for a result like this:

```
| MonthNumber | Code | Figure |
|-------------|------|--------|
|           5 |    S |     25 |
|           5 |    G |     30 |
|           5 |    K |     30 |
|           5 |    D |      0 |
|           5 |    J |      0 |
```

I want to limit the figures to month 5 but also bring back all people even if they didnt have a figure. I thought using right join syntax would be the correct thing for this but its not giving me the result i want. I cant really work out the logic i need. Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Why third line must be 5, K, 30 instead of null, K, null? The same for other two last lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An outer join seems right.  Why are you using `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`?  The latter is usually simpler to follow.

```
SELECT '5' as MonthNumber, p.[Code], COALESCE(f.Figure, 0) as Figure
FROM Person P LEFT JOIN
     Figure F
     ON F.[Code] = P.[Code] AND F.MonthNumber = '5';
```

The condition on the second table (in a `LEFT JOIN`) needs to go in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Why would a right join not work with your scenario if you reversed the joining order of the tables?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon . . . Of course, `RIGHT JOIN` would work.  I just find it much less intuitive.  Keeping all rows in the first table makes sense.  Keeping all rows in the last table (which I haven't read yet) doesn't make as much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what it should, but not what your asking exactly because of the data:

```
SELECT F.[MonthNumber], -- this wont select 5 for all rows, but you can hard code this to the 5
P.[Code],
ISNULL(f.[Figure], 0) AS Figure
FROM 
Person P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Figure F ON P.[Code] = F.[Code]
    AND F.[MonthNumber] = '5'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like below.

update fiddle -http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6552d/24

```
SELECT 
MonthNumber= ISNULL(MonthNumber,'5'),
P.Code,
Figure= ISNULL(Figure,0)
FROM 
Figure F
RIGHT JOIN Person P
ON F.[Code] = P.[Code]
AND F.[MonthNumber] ='5'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this I hope it helps

CREATE TABLE #Figure(
MonthNumber varchar(10),
Code varchar(10),
Figure int
);

INSERT INTO #Figure (MonthNumber, Code, Figure)
VALUES ('5', 'S', '25'),
('5','G', '30'),
('4','K', '30');

CREATE TABLE #Person(
Code varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO #Person (Code)
VALUES ('S'),
('G' ),
('K' ),
('D' ),
('J');



SELECT F.[MonthNumber],
P.[Code],
f.[Figure]
FROM #Person  p
LEFT  JOIN #Figure F
ON P.[Code] = F.[Code]

WHERE F.[MonthNumber] = '5' 
or F.[MonthNumber] is null
```